# Why am I getting memory leak warning in console while setting the state of a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of React Code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Aux/Aux';
import Axios from 'axios';

const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            });
            this.respInterceptor =axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
            });

        }

        componentWillUnmount(){
            Axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
            Axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.respInterceptor);
        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
            this.setState({error: null});
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <Aux>
                    <Modal 
                        show={this.state.error}
                        modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
                        {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                    </Modal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </Aux>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

It generates the following warning in the console :

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in _temp (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Then I replaced the constructor part with this :

```
        componentDidMount(){
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            });
            this.respInterceptor =axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
            });
        }
```

The same warning kept appearing.

Then I changes `componentDidMount` above with this :

```
        componentDidUpdate(){
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                this.setState({error: null});
                return req;
            });
            this.respInterceptor =axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
                this.setState({error: error});
            });
        }
```

Then the warning sometimes goes and sometimes appears.

In my code I use the above wrapper component in only two places this way:
`export default WithErrorHandler(Orders, Axios);`  `export default WithErrorHandler(BurgerBuilder, Axios);`

then when I export the components normally without a wrapper the warning goes away, hence this is not what I want to do to solve this. So I'm sure the warning is coming from the wrapper.

I know the life cycle of a component but this is something that I do not get it, why this warning keeps coming out, is that related to the anonymous class component returned or has something to do with it ?, what is the problem ?

Comment: The problem, as indicated by the error message, is that you are trying to update the state after the component was unmounted or before it was mounted. It says that this is a memory leak because, well, the callback still has a reference to the component instance even though it's not rendered anymore. I'd add more log messages into the life cycle methods and try to find out why the component gets unmounted.

Comment: I would guess that `axios` and `Axios` are not always resolving to the same instance depending on usage, so ejecting the interceptors doesn't always work.

Comment: it is ok for the component to get unmounted since I'm navigating between them throw routes. so when i click the navigation link to go from one to another the warning appears. I understand that the component is unmounted but why there is still a call back reference that tries to update the state after unmounting. till this moment the log messages could not help, also i searched for it but got no clear idea about what is the problem yet. however i will try that again to log messages.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen I check it now, you are absolutely right.
I checked the import above in the question, I wrote `import Axios from 'axios';`  and used the default instance, so that was I typo , hence I should imported my instance that I defined which is this `import Axios from '../../axios-orders';`.

thank you I kept logging messages from life cycle methods and they did not help to get me think about this and I did not guess it as I'm new to react.

Comment: so that the actual problem was that the promise does point to a separate instance of `axios` which causes the setState inside it to be fired after the component gets unmounted.

but why it fires when the component gets unmounted only.
why did not that happen for example before the component gets unmounted, this really makes me wonder about it.

but i think such thing should not just be a warning in react, that should result in an error. hell I'm trying to set the state after the component is gone, it is more like an error not a warning.It like I'm hitting null + not cleaning my memory.

Comment: Looking more closely, this approach will not be safe to use if you ever have more than one component constructed this way on the page at once. Using and modifying an imported axios instance means that multiple components will be adding and removing interceptors at the same time. Components will try to handle errors from calls they didn't make. A safer option would be to create a new axios instance (`axios.create()`) each time the `withErrorHandler` function is used, either in the constructor, or `componentWillMount` function.

Comment: couldn't agree more. thank you @PatrickStephansen.